# Добавление изображений из CSS расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. 
**Вопрос:** как задать путь из файла CSS ? 
При таком задании пути, изображение не подключается.

файл: my_style.css

```
.myBackground { background: url(../images/img.jpg) no-repeat; }
```

Comment: все зависит от того где у вас находится файл my_style.css

Comment: В папке css расширения. указал путь в манифест: "web_accessible_resources" :  [ "images/*.png", "images/*.jpg", "css/my_style.css" ]

Comment: Подскажите как решить задачу.

Comment: попробуйте прописать полный путь к файлу, а не относительный как у вас сейчас. Возможно у вас имя картинки задано неверно.

Comment: Тогда скорее не полный путь, а что то типа этого url(chrome-extension://pejpkhcnebcgabbemkikcoobameengen/images/img.png"), а можно ли сделать что бы было автоматически, 1 раз указав: в манифесте или коде путь, а потом указывая только имя картинки: img.jpg, или img.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, работоспособность будет зависить от того, где находится `my_style.css`.

Можете использовать относительные `url` или абсолютные.

Относительный что-то вроде:

```
background: url(/images/myImage.jpg)
```

Абсолютный выглядит так:

```
chrome-extension://<extensionID>/<pathToFile>
```

Где `extensionID` уникальный идентификатор который генерируется для каждого расширения.

А `pathToFile` это тот же относительный `url`.

Во время работы над расширением `extensionID` может менятся, для того чтобы использовать абсолютные `url`, вам нужно воспользоваться [predefined messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined). А именно `@@extension_id`.

Тогда `url` будет следующим:

```
background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/myImage.png');
```

Индитификатор `extensionID` становится постоянным после упаковки расширения, в этом случае `@@extension_id` можно заменить на полученный `id` расширения.

[Referring to files](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#relative-urls). Тут так же описаны еще несколько ситуаций в которых `extensionID` может изменится.

Еще `@@extension_id` нельзя использовать в `manifest.json`.

Если решите программно задавать, тут уже можно воспользоваться функцией 
[getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL).

```
var path = chrome.extension.getURL('images/myImage.png');
```

А дальше использовать переменную `path` в функции [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: То есть: __MSG_@@extension_id__  это константа равная уникальному идентификатору abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef  ?

Comment: @Макс, из документации:
`background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/background.png');`

Если `extensionID` abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef, то код выше будет подобен

`background-image:url('chrome-extension://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef/background.png');` . Так что да.  

`это константа`
Я честно затрудняюсь сказать. Не константа точно. Константа все-таки постоянное значение имеет. А `extensionID` может изменятся.
Скорее это просто свойство какого-то json объекта, которое при первой загрузке расширения устанавливается.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, вам.